# error : No accelerated colorspace conversion found., vision_opencv stack in ros,avi video file processing

Tags: opencv, ffmpeg, avi

When i try to run some custom node to process some .avi video i have this error : i guess this error is related to opencv , i have tried all the sloutions , even recompiled vision_opencv with FFMPEG flag on , and urgraded ffmped with --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-swscale , but still no luck .

```
[swscaler @ 0x842fa20]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
Last message repeated 10 times 
[swscaler @ 0x8497c80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.  
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found. 
Last message repeated 10 times 
[swscaler @ 0x8497c60]No accelerated colorspace conversion found. 
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
Last message repeated 10 times 
[swscaler @ 0x8495730]No accelerated colorspace conversion found. 
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
Last message repeated 10 times 
[swscaler @ 0x8492ae0]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found. 
Last message repeated 10 times 
[swscaler @ 0x8492d00]No accelerated colorspace conversion found.
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found. 
Last message repeated 10 times
[swscaler @ 0x8491c70]No accelerated colorspace conversion found. 
[swscaler @ 0x848aa80]No accelerated colorspace conversion found
```

i can't proceed with my project , until i sort this out and i already have wasted more than 10hrs on this problem , so if you guys think of any solution i would be glad to try it out .

Comment: Could you please format this properly? http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but:

http://libav-users.943685.n4.nabble.com/No-accelerated-colorspace-conversion-found-td946602.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is an ffmpeg bug/feature: not all conversions are accelerated. When compiling my own ffmepg 0.6.2 or 0.7 rc1, those warnings disappeared (the Ubuntu version seems to have them). Not sure of the flags to use though.

via @vincent http://answers.ros.org/question/1229/no-accelerated-colorspace-conversion-found